# Make Fixed Position Div Stop before footer

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a scroll and fixed div position, i want that to stop just before it reaches footer, because its overlapping over footer.

here is the code so far

```
<script>
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 330) {
            $('#stickyblock').addClass('position-fixed');
            $('#stickyblock').removeClass('sticky-top');
        } else {
            $('#stickyblock').removeClass('position-fixed');
            $('#stickyblock').addClass('sticky-top');
        }
    });
</script>
```

this detect the header and fix the div to top, but i want it to stop being fixed when it hit the footer.

html code

```
    <div id="header">Navigation and Logo</div>

<!-- First Row, here sticky element starts scrolling -->
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row>
    <div class="col-md-8">some content</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="sticky-top" id="stickyblock">some buttons or block of code</div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    
    <!--another row and full width container, where scroll should change from sticky to fixed-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row>
    <div class="col-md-8">some content</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    blank space(for fixed element to show)
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    
    <!--footer starts, here fixed div should stop-->
    <div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: can you help me with a bit of example code with my existing code.

Comment: I have updated the html, i am using bootstrap4 class for fixed and sticky

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you should do is use the `position: sticky;` CSS property, along with specifying `top`. You will not need to use JavaScript at all.
Here's a snippet:

```css
.footer {
  height: 1000px;
}

.container {
  height: 1000px;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sticky">Sticky bar</div>
</div>

<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

If you do want/need to use jQuery, you should add to your `if` statement a check for the `scrollTop()` to be of a lower value than the top position of the footer in the page. Depending on the jQuery version, one of the following snippets will fit your case:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() >= 320 && $(window).scrollTop() < $('#footer').offset().top) ...
```

or

```
if($(window).scrollTop() >= 320 && $(window).scrollTop() < $('#footer').offsetTop) ...
```

Comment: Hi, Cristian, i have updated my question with Html code structure example, 
i have used this sticky class, but i needed to continue that sticky thing to next row below its parent row, thats why i changed it from sticky to fixed.

here is the example of my page where goal needs to be achieved - https://api.happyvoyaging.com/en/tour-packages/114/historical-highlights-of-greece-8-day-tour

Comment: @GauravSingh Thanks for the notification. I have also edited the last part of my answer as I noticed I missed something. In your case, the second option (with the extra condition) should work as that does not care about the structure of the containers. Please tell if it fits your case

Comment: Sir I have tried to replace my if statement with yours, this does not seems to be working.

Comment: @GauravSingh Please check this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y4cpbjz5/

Comment: Sir, I can see that in your fiddle it is working as expected, but when i implement your code in my live page, it still overlapping the footer and not working.

Comment: you can check it at live page that i have given in first comment, thanks for your support sir.

Comment: Thanks mate! i made it to work, your answer helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;
var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                       html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
var footer = document.getElementsByTagName("footer")[0];
                       
$(window).scrollTop() > height - window.height or 
$(window).scrollTop() > height - footer.height - 600 //how many pixels do you want
```

Comment: Thanks Razvan for the idea ! Yours and Cristian code gave me idea to work around it.